# Competition scoring/ranking algorithm

Tags: algorithm

### The gist

I'm implementing a website that hosts fitness competitions, and I need a good way to generate a "score" or "rank".

### How the competitions work

Competitions consist of a team of one or more athletes/contestants from a given gym challenging the same number of contestants from one or more other gyms. There isn't any limit to the number of gyms that can enter the competition - there could potentially be over one hundred gyms that enter the competition. Points are assigned to each team based on various factors: time, reps, heaviest lift, etc.

Attributing a score to each team within a single competition is the easy part; things get a little more interesting when we try to generate a ranking for each gym based on their history of competitions. Intuitively, a team that places 1st amongst 10 other gyms in a competition should rank higher than a team that places 1st among 5 other gyms from a different competition.

I'm having trouble coming up with an intuitive, fair ranking mechanism. Any concrete ideas or suggestions on perhaps a family of ranking algorithms would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, Not programming related (IMHO) (if you had a ranking system and needed an algrorithm to express it, then that would be "programming related")

Answer (score 4):

Check out TrueSkill used in Halo to rank players.
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/trueskill/details.aspx 
ELO only deals with 1v1 whereas TrueSkill can deal with teams of 1 or more players and multiple teams.

There are also online calculators if you don't want to code anything.
If you want code examples, the original is available in F#, Jeff Moser re-coded it in C# and recently PHP.
Google "Jeff Moser Computing skill"

Answer (score 1):

How about treating each team as 'beating' all the teams it placed above in a particular competition, and 'losing' to all teams it placed below? You could then compute an [ELO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) for each team over time.

Comment: ELO makes sanse in one tournament where each player had equal number of games. But here, as I understand, other gyms can join later and they would be in great disadvantage to the oldest ones (having lots of wins and losses already).

Comment: @Nikita Rybak: As I understand the question, a *single* tournament will not have gyms entering late; the competitors are decided ahead of time. And ELO is perfectly capable of ranking competitors who have played a different number of games, so gyms who miss a few competitions should not get unduly disadvantaged.

Comment: @Ani I quote question "Attributing a score to each team within a single competition is the easy part; things get a little more interesting when we try to generate a ranking for each gym based on their history of competitions."

Comment: @Nikita Rybak: Exactly, that's why ELO is fine. It would only be a problem if a single competition doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Ani I think we're talking about different things. There's no concept of "tournament" in the question. It looks like competitions just happen from time to time and there's need to determine best gym basing on "history of competitions".

Comment: @Nikita Rybak: As I mention in my answer, treat a competition as a tournament.

Comment: @Ani And ELO makes sense within single tournament only. We don't use it to 'extrapolate' data from past 15 tournaments, right?

Comment: @Nikita Rybak: Your ELO score for that tournament will impact your overall ELO rating. So it is stateful.

Comment: @Ani: this definitely sounds like what I'm after. I like the fact that an entry level competitor (`A`) can "catch up" to other highly ranked competitors (`B`) when `A` beats `B`. From briefly reading the wikipedia link, it looks like this system is also used on online games, which I feel share a lot in common with the type of competition I'm talking about. Thank you for this answer - I think this could be what I end up using.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the competition as gym. Maybe the fair rank depends on their muscle which surely relies on how many exercise they have done and how regular it is. Of course some variable from 'before' and 'after' exercising must be taken. In a brief, calculate the effectiveness of the exercise they do.

### For example:

Normally, when exercise x is done 40 times, one can increase his muscle 5 points

Mr. A does exercise x 30 times and got 4 muscle.
Hence Score for Mr. A = (4 / 30 ) / (5 / 40)

The total score is the sum of another exercise done by Mr. A. Total = Score(x) + Score(y) + Score(z)

This is fair enough since the actual result is compared directly to expected result. This can also prevents a stronger person taking an easy exercise. Since, you know, Arnold Schwarzenegger can't increase his muscle using 1 kg dumbell.

Of course the unit (muscle) may vary depends on the exercise.

Comment: I think he said that this part ("Attributing a score to each team within a single competition") is trivial :)